# How to make Unity NavMeshAgent path around the player

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

in my project there's a Unity Multipurpose Avatar Crowd that uses the NavMeshAgent component. However when in VR it will come very close to the player in a very intimidating way, it be best to avoid that. Been trying to get the to path around the player, but not quite sure how.
Things tried so far:

1. Putting a NavMeshAgent on the player - this makes them able to push the player if he's in their path
2. NavMeshObstacle on the player - this makes the AI sink into the ground if the player approaches them

Thinking the best way to do is in a script, but not entirely sure how to just slightly go around the player keeping the current desired destination.

Comment: I believe using NavMeshObstacle on the player with *carve* set to true and a *big enough shape (capsule or box)* will make all the NavMeshAgents path around the player without ever going too close (inside his bounding box) to him

Comment: Hadn't checked the box and it worked decent, but carving the path made them sink into the ground again, however only carving when stationary seemed to fix it. Thank you.